# Java: String to BigInteger to Binary

Tags: string, binary, java.util.scanner, biginteger

I have a problem where I want to turn my input string into a BigInteger, and the output should be a Binary String. I used this code, but all it can read is "0" and "1".

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = scan.nextLine();
BigInteger big = new BigInteger(input, 2);
String binarystring = big.toString(2);
System.out.println(binarystring);
```

When I change it to: `BigInteger big = new BigInteger(input, 16);` 
I can write in a hexadecimal number but with no space.

What I want is that I can write any string, and the program should give me its binary value in a string.

Comment: How would you determine which base the input String is in? Are you restricting it to say, binary, Octal, decimal, or hexadecimal? Will the user add characters before the number (ex. 0xDEADBEEF) to indicate the base?

Comment: @user1071777 No, the input should be in normal characters(alphabet and numbers), but the output should be in Binary. And no the user doesnt need to put anything to indicate the base

Comment: What I'm saying is, how can you know whether an input string "345" is in base 8 or base 10 or base 16 or anything higher than base 6? Without knowing the base, there could be any number of binary representations. Ex. 345 in base 8 to binary is 11100101, 345 in base 10 is 101011001, etc.

Comment: @user1071777 Okay I understand what you mean, so the input ofc shouldn't be numbers only, my input string can be for ex "hey world". When the input cointains numbers they should be in base 10. I don't know if you can set your string("hey world") into a base, but if you can i want that in base 10 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string like "hey world" won't have any meaningful numeric representation in base 10, so I suggest to output an appropriate message instead.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = scan.nextLine();
try {
    BigInteger big = new BigInteger(input); // default constructor is base 10
    System.out.println(big.toString(2));
}
catch (NumberFormatException){
    System.out.println("Input was not a decimal number");
}
```

Comment: Okay Thanks this helped me a little, if you could give me a code where  I can convert my Input into a decimal number and use that for the BigInteger big, that would be great. Either way Thanks ;)

Comment: The default constructor for BigInteger tries to parse the input as a decimal (base 10) representation.

Comment: okay but when I type in something like "test" it says: NumberFormatException: For input string: "test" and thats i want to do, to convert the input into a decimal value FIRST and then give it to the BigInteger.

Comment: Yes, that's expected because "test" is not actually a number in base 10. The try catch block should catch the NumberFormatException and output an appropriate message.

If you don't want to use a try catch, you could look into http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/math/NumberUtils.html#isNumber(java.lang.String) or create your own isNumber method to use.

Comment: okay I have found the problem and the solution, even though i first have to convert my input into a hex. and then convert it to binary. But I appreciate your help ;) THX